# How to add cart sidebar on customer_account_create page

Tags: magento-1.9, sidebar

I want to add cart sidebar in `customer_account_create` and `customer_account_login` page for this I have added code in local.xml file as:

```
...
<customer_account_login translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>

    <customer_account_create translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
...
```

But it is not showing sidebar cart in right sidebar.
While the same code is working for category view and product view page.

How to add cart in right sidebar on customer create and login page?

Comment: It's display 2columns right sidebar ?

Comment: Yes, it is display right sidebar, and right sidebar has only one block `product-compare`. And I want to add sidebar cart.

Comment: please can you clear cache

Comment: I have cleared cache before and once again, but not working.

Comment: sure i check and local and has back to you with updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml`:

**`<remove name="right"/>`** has removed the block, therefore you cannot reference it.

```
<!--
Layout for customer login page
-->

<customer_account_login translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Same deal for `<customer_account_create>`:

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Form Fields Before</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: `<remove name="right"/>` not in my xml file, and `account_create` and `accoubt_login` page display right sidebar, and right sidebar has only one block `product-compare`. And I want to add `My Cart` also.

Answer (score 2):

In `customer.xml` of your theme, remove `<remove name="right"/>` from `customer_account_create` and `customer_account_login` handles.

Now in `local.xml`, add following code :

```
<layout>

    ....

    <customer_account_login>
        <update handle="page_two_columns_right"/>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>

    <customer_account_create>
        <update handle="page_two_columns_right"/>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>

    ...

</layout>
```

**MUST CHECK** : Go to admin, `System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart Sidebar`, now check `Display Shopping Cart Sidebar` must be set to `Yes`